# I need to responses messageID in logica SMPP async mode

Tags: sms, smpp

In logica smpp I need to stored response message ID in asynchronous mode.

```
if (sb.asynchronous)     
 {                                  
   System.out.println("Submit request " + request.debugString());
                                                sb.getSession().submit(request);

  //messageId = response.getMessageId();
 } else {

   response = sb.getSession().submit(request);

   messageId = response.getMessageId().trim();
  }
```

In the above code. How we can get messageID in  asynchronous mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get Message id by `getSmDefaultMsgId()` by calling it with `SubmitSM` 's object . like below:

```
  if (sb.asynchronous)     
 {                                  
   System.out.println("Submit request " + request.debugString());
                                                sb.getSession().submit(request);

  messageId = request.getSmDefaultMsgId();
 }
```

For more documentation you can read [this tutorial](https://github.com/cornet/logica-smpp/blob/master/com/logica/smpp/pdu/SubmitSM.java)

Thanks. Let me know if it helped.

Comment: In asynchronous mode i'm getting always messageID=0 .There is no other option so ,I need to keep a correlation between the message and its response use the "sequence number" that is both in the message and the response.but how it is possible can you explain?

Comment: well I am not able to find if there is a way unless you make your own custom classes which extends SubmitSMResp and SubmitSM and put a variable for id in both cases which'll makes every req and response specific. What I know is we have "DFLT_MSGID" static variable in Data class. this variable tells you the message id. so you can try with this too as
messageId = Data.DFLT_MSGID; give it a try.